# Invalid data (???????) returned from SQL Server stored procedure addressing linked Oracle server

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, stored-procedures

We have the following scenario: process is to return string with Greek letters using an Oracle stored procedure on output.

Oracle function (example) is :

```
FUNCTION GREEKLATINSTRING (a_latin_name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
 IS
 BEGIN RETURN 'ΣΤΡΟΒΟΛΟΣ/123/ABC'; END;
```

This function is called from within a T-SQL stored procedure (please assume all connections are 100% as we have other procedures executing w/o issues)

TSQL stored procedure is :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GreekLatinString] @NameLatin NVARCHAR(100)
AS 
    DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = N'BEGIN ? := LINKED_SERVER.DB_INSTANCE.GREEKLATINSTRING(?); END;';

    EXECUTE(@SQL, 
            @output            OUTPUT    ,
            @NameGr                      ) --1Params
            AT MYORACLE;

    SELECT cast (@output as nvarchar)
END
```

And C# code is nothing special - simply getting data back:

```
dbCommand = CreateCommand();
dbCommand.Transaction = ModelContext.CurrentDBUtils.Transaction;
dbCommand.CommandText = "GreekLatinString";
dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter param0 = new SqlParameter("NameLatin", nameLatin);
param0.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param0);

using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand as SqlCommand))
{
   adapter.Fill(dataset);
}
```

SQL Server instance collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AS` AND Oracle `NLS_LANG` is `al32utf8`

Problem is that whenever function is executed directly in Oracle it returns value as it should, however whenever we call is from C# from inside of SQL Server stored procedure the output in the dataset is always `????????`

Can anybody suggest what might be the reason for that?

Comment: Try BEGIN RETURN N'ΣΤΡΟΒΟΛΟΣ';

Comment: From the code, `greek_to_latin` looks like it is returning Greek letters, so I'm unclear why it is called `greek_to_latin`. I've not heard of `al8utf8`, and could find no reference to it in Oracle's globalization guide. http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/index.htm#A

Comment: If I understand. You can call `greek_to_latin` on the Oracle box and get correct results. Calling `GreekToLatin` from C# gives `????...`. What about `GreekToLatin` directly in SQL Server from SSMS?

Comment: If you inspect the byte values of that what do you see? Is your app able to display greek letters from other sources (i.e. hard coded)

Comment: @Frisbee I've changed a bit explanation please have a look again + i provided return value as example. Normally we return varchar2 output variable from oracle. Is there a way to force N' ' like behaviour for var and not some const string ?

Comment: Did you  you try what i said or not?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Sorry for confusion - I've updated explanation for problem to be more concrete for my problem. Oracle has NLS_Lang al32utf8 (mistype sorry).  Problem appears exactly at this step when i execute either via c# or directly stored procedure in mssql - the output value is ????? for all greek chars

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The problem appears already on the MSSQL level. Calling it from C# is not as important - i've just provided full stack scenario

Comment: @Frisbee can you check my comment just above yours ;) u've asked just after I added it.

"Normally we return varchar2 output variable from oracle. Is there a way to force N' ' like behaviour for var and not some const string ? "

Comment: Is English a second language?   Did you try what I said or not?

Comment: @Frisbee Same result as output ?????? even if I added N' '

Comment: Why minus guys ? I'm simply trying to find a solution to the problem and possibly help anyone encountering same issues ...

Comment: So what does `SELECT UNICODE ( @YourResult )` return in SSMS? I wonder if its correct but SSMS just can't display it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've modified procedure to return each character unicode value and it's 63 which stands for ?

Comment: 63 is a question mark :). Now we know that question marks are really being sent and it is not just that SSMS can't display unicode characters.

Comment: Which provider are you using? Apparently MSDAORA dpesn't support unicode: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244661 (although this may be out of date). Maybe try the Oracle OLE DB provider not the MS one (which is just a wrapper)

Comment: It just occurred to me... why not connect directly to Oracle with your C# app? Linked servers are always unreliable

Comment: What about standard characters-  do they come across OK? If you want me to stop suggesting stuff, just let me know

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Please give ideas, don't stop - you don't know when we can come up with solution. We cannot go directly from C# to Oracle due to security restrictions related to project rules and our application talks only to our MSSQL DB and only MSSQL talks to Remote Oracle DB.

Comment: So really the linked server is a technical workaround - understood. So anyway try returning normal characters - do they come through?

Comment: Further to @ShannonSeverance comment below, when you saw the correct characters when running directly in Oracle as mentioned in the original post, was this done _on the SQL Server using SQLPlus (or SQL Developer)?_. If it was, it implies the client character set is actually correct and troubleshooting next to take place at the next layer

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid. _If it was, it implies the client character set is actually correct._ Unfortunately, it only suggests, but does not imply. Different sessions/connections can have different client character sets **on the same** client machine.

Comment: We'll need to wait for confirmation but if this _was_ seen on the client, does it mean the step is to confirm that the linked server uses these same client settings? How does a client set the character set?

Comment: Here is a function to covert from UTF-8 to UTF-16, but based on the `SELECT UNICODE` test, the data is already corrupted by the time it gets into SQL http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=62406

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The client character set is a part of `NLS_LANG`. On UNIX `NLS_LANG` is an environment variable. On Windows, registry entries that can be overridden by an environment variable. (Look up NLS_LANG in Oracle's Globalization Guide.) But the setting can be further overridden by the client **application**. For example sqlldr loading a file with a different character set.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but got too long for a comment:

When the character set of an Oracle database and Oracle client are different Oracle will perform [translation of character data](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch2charset.htm#NLSPG174) in both directions. If the target character set does not support a source character Oracle will substitute something valid. In many single byte character sets that something is `?`, in Unicode character sets u+FFFD, `REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`, is used.

Note that the client character set is is not fixed for a client machine, but *can* be set at the connection level.

In this case then:

1. Character data is sourced in the Oracle database character set. This character data includes Greek letters.
2. The character data is sent to the Oracle *client* used by SQL Server's linked DB connection. If the client character set and database character set differ, translation will occur.
3. From the Oracle client the character data may travel through other software layers. (For example OLE DB.)
4. The character data is taken into SQL Server.
5. The character data is displayed. The Greek letters have become question marks.

My guess is that the Oracle client character set at step 2 is a single byte character set that does not support Greek letters and that at this step the characters are translated to question marks. This is where I would begin an investigation. Again, the client character set is not set for the machine so one can't start up SQL*Plus on the SQL Server machine and say, "Works, problem not in the Oracle client character set." since SQL*Plus may be using something different from SQL Server.

Once you have verified that the Oracle client character set is suitable and if you still have a problem, you'll have to figure out how to work forward. I don't have any guidance to offer. Maybe write a simple client application against the same OLE DB drivers you are using. I'm not sure.

Comment: This is great information. Can you clarify: if data is stored in Oracle in the same column, and that data is both Greek characters and Chinese characters, can the Oracle client only display one set of these characters (depending on the client character set?)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid If the Oracle Client character set is one of Oracle's "Universal Character Sets" and the client software can correctly consume and display that character set there would be no limit on which characters can be displayed. Oracle's AL32UTF8 is Unicode's UTF-8 so we aren't talking anything super exotic for 2015. Though Oracle's documentation seems to imply that Unicode client character sets don't work on Windows. But, um, they do, sometimes at least. Documentation link for Universal Character Sets: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/applocaledata.htm#NLSPG589

Comment: I don't understand why UTF-8 in the Oracle DB and UTF-8 in the client wouldn't "just work" for all characters. Maybe it does, and the problem is that T-SQL just doesn't support UTF-8 http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/sql-server-2005-2008-utf-8-collation-charset

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, but T-SQL does support Unicode in the _N_ types which are UCS-2 (and we'll pretend that's UTF-16 thank you very much.). OP is using _N_ types in SQL Server. One would hope that if it was AL32UTF8 in the Oracle DB, and AL32UTF8 in the Oracle client, that between the Oracle client software and the T-SQL _N_ strings there would be a translation between UTF-8 and UCS-2. I don't have any idea if that translation happens, or what needs to be configured to make it happen. Or setting the client character set to AL16UTF16 which more closely matches SQL Server's _N_ types is better.

Comment: We are trying to identify now as per your suggestions where is the actual problem happening - will update as soon as we get the results